# The "right" way to calculate subtotals using SQL

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have a table that looks like this

```
Person#  |  Person Name   | Gender | Persons Net Worth
-----------------------------------------------------------
1          Donald J           M        20
2          George W           M        20
3          Mark   B           T        20
4          Hil    C           F        20
5          Hil    C           F        20
6          Bill   C           M        20
7          Eric   Z           M        20
8          Caitl  J           T        20
```

I want to gather subtotals for each *gender* group. I need to essentially

incorporate a `sum(NETWORTH) where gender = 'M' group by gender sort by gender`

and a

`sum(NETWORTH) where gender = 'F' group by gender sort by gender`

and a

`sum(NETWORTH) where gender = 'T' group by gender sort by gender`

So I basically want the result to be this:

```
Person#  |  Person Name   | Gender | Persons Net Worth
-----------------------------------------------------------
1          Donald J           M        20
2          George W           M        20
6          Bill   C           M        20
7          Eric   Z           M        20
                                Total: 80
4          Hil    C           F        20
5          Hil    C           F        20
                                Total: 40
3          Mark   B           T        20
8          Caitl  J           T        20
                                Total: 40
```

I tried using `WITH ROLLUP` but ended up failing miserably. I know how to manipulate in the code behind to achieve this but I'd rather do it all in one SQL Query if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `grouping sets` (see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_groupingexamples.html)):

```
select Person#, Name, Gender, sum(networth) as networth
from t
group by grouping sets ( (#Person, Name, Gender), (Gender));
```

Although this appears to do an extra aggregation, the syntax is flexible for all sorts of subtotals.  For instance, if you wanted the overall total as well:

```
group by grouping sets ( (#Person, Name, Gender), (Gender), ());
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon. EXTREMELY helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: you use `union all` with the table and its aggregation by `gender`, using as `gender` value in the aggregated one something similar to the original `gender`, that allows you to sort the final table as desired.

```
select  *
from    (
            select  *
            from    yourTable
            union all
            select  null, null, CONCAT(Gender, '_TOT'), sum(Persons_net_worth)
            from    yourTable
            group by CONCAT(Gender, '_TOT')
        )
order by Gender
```

I'm not proficient in DB2 Oracle, this may need some tweaking

Comment: That's the old way of doing it.  The problem is that the table is read multiple times.  Thus the reason `grouping sets` functionality was added to DB2 (and most other DBMS)